# Any piece of advice for audio streaming (on demand) stack, commercial, free and open source?

Tags: web-apps, sql, streaming, audio-player, flac

I could **not** see (m)any of free, open source, available for commercial projects, stack, from back end to front end, for flac audio streaming (not radio, but audio on demand).

To start with, is SQL server a good base to store the full files ? Should the audio chunks be prepared before or on the fly ? I'm planning to use also .NET 6 on the back end side (as webserver, together with IIS / Nginx as proxy).

On the front end, I could not find many open and free for commercial projects flac readers. In 2022, could I use a regular flac reader or libraries and use the webassembly possibility?

Comment: SQL Server can store raw data as binary blobs. However, a SQL database provides no advantages to this kind of data.

However, why would you not simply use a filesystem for that? Where does the requirement to use an SQL database come into play?

Comment: @jpaugh Surprising statement and question ! Access (through tcp, from local machine and other machines), availability (in RAM storage), sql, searches, order etc. Which advantages are lost according to you point fo view ?

Comment: I don't believe by itself SQL plays a big part into the solution you're looking for, even though it could address some of your concerns together with custom software. Generally, SQL is not used to provide network access to data; rather a website is used instead and that can provide access to either data from SQL, or data from a filesystem.

As far as building a search database, you could export various metadata from each file into a SQL table and use that for searching. However, storing the raw file contents in the same table would only serve to slow down your db access.

Comment: If you have software development skills (and it sounds like you do),  I'd recommend just storing the filename in the SQL table instead, along with whatever data you want to search against, and once you've completed a search, your web app can read the file from disk to stream it.

Comment: As far as prepping the files, it probably makes sense to encode them with whichever stream-friendly codec you have in mind at the time you save them to disk, since that operation would otherwise have to happen every time someone access the original flac files. I don't know *which* audio codecs support streaming, however. It could be that flac works fine as is.

Comment: @jpaugh Very wise indeed. Flac codec and container is OK but not perfect, ogg-flac (ogg container, flac codec) is more fexible and more appropriate for that. Now I'm on making the reading of consecutive chunks seamless.